# how to build an program with classes in c++

Tags: c++, makefile

I have to write a simple class library. There are two classes `Element` and `Permutation`.

File Element.h

```
#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

class Element
{
public: 
    virtual ~Element()=0;
    virtual bool IsEven()=0;
    virtual bool IsNeutral()=0;
};

#endif
```

File Permutation.h

```
#ifndef PERMUTATION_H
#define PERMUTATION_H

#include "Element.h"

class Permutation: public Element
{
private:
    int* numbers; 

public:
    const int k;
    Permutation(const int, int*); 
    Permutation(const int); 
    Permutation(); 
    ~Permutation(); 
    int NumberOfInversions(); 
    bool IsEven(); 
    bool IsNeutral(); 

    friend Permutation operator+(const Permutation&, const Permutation&); 
    friend Permutation operator-(const Permutation&); 
};

#endif
```

And I have Permutation.cpp that implements class Permutation. Class Element is abstract, so it has not any .cpp file with realization. So, I want to write a simple test program (with main) that uses class Permutation. How should I build my project? I use g++ compiler on linux platform.

Here is my Makefile that doesn't work:

```
all: permutation_test

permutation_test: fuf.o Permutation.o 
    g++ fuf.o Permutation.o -o permutation_test
fuf.o: fuf.cpp
    g++ -c fuf.cpp 
Permutation.o: Permutation.cpp 
    g++ -c Permutation.cpp 

clean:
   rm -rf *o permuatation_test
```

(fuf.cpp contains the main method.)
error:
Permutation.o: in function «Permutation::Permutation(int, int*)»:
Permutation.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference «Element::Element()»
Permutation.o: in function «Permutation::Permutation(int)»:
Permutation.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference «Element::Element()»
Permutation.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference «Element::~Element()»
Permutation.o: in function «Permutation::Permutation()»:
Permutation.cpp:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference «Element::Element()»
Permutation.o: in function «Permutation::~Permutation()»:
Permutation.cpp:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference «Element::~Element()»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

It works now. thanks for replies. I have just replaced pure virtual destructor with virtual and deleted constructor in class Element

Comment: @combinatorial: My bet is on a linker error because the definition of `~Element` doesn't exist.

Comment: Don't make the destructor pure-virtual. Instead, say `virtual ~Element() { }`.

Comment: `virtual ~Element()=0;` ? Something new added to the language while i was sleeping (again)? You may want to define "doesn't work" with a little more clarity (like an error code+message)

Comment: `~Element()` is pure virtual, so it shouldn't need to exist. But until the OP tells us what the error is, or shows us the contents of the .cpp files, guessing isn't going to be very productive.

Comment: "Permutation.cpp:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference «Element::~Element()» " this is error occured when I make program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you make the destructor pure virtual, you still need to provide a definition for it, otherwise the subclass' destructor can never call it, like it must.

To fix the compilation error, add

```
inline Element::~Element() {}
```

to Element.h.

(It's not well known that you can provide definitions for pure virtual functions.)

There's some discussion of providing definition for pure virtuals in an old [Guru of the Week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/031.htm) by Herb Sutter.

**On the other hand:**
I must say that in this case, it makes very little sense to have a pure virtual destructor - I can't think of any other use for one than to make a class abstract when it doesn't have any other virtual functions.

The best solution would be to ditch `Element`'s destructor altogether, as it serves no purpose other than to cause confusion.